# How to send automatic email after 5 and 8 minutes of login

Tags: php, cron

I am working on a PHP application where I have to send automatic sms/email after user send request.

USER-1 sends request to USER-2, if there is no response from USER-2 (i.e. Do not accept the request or rejects the request), then after 5-minutes user-2 should get email/sms to take action on request. If User-2 still takes action then after 8-minutes request of User-1 should get cancelled.

But I have no idea how to do?

Comment: you have to a setup cron job. After the login, you have to insert the job to be executed in the database and in your cron script you need to fetch the job from the database and do according to your need .

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have some kind of scheduler which take care of this kind of work.

This could be for example a cronjob or jenkins which is running a script all x minutes. This script is looking for any kind of changes that you want to threat.
You could for example save the timestamp when the message was sent to another user.

Your script requests then all items from your database where the time between now and the saved timestamp is greater than 8 minutes.

Sending emails for that etc.